# How to create log for a complete thread

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, logging

How can we create a log for complete thread of execution?

I would like to see if it is possible to get log for complete execution (for example if a request is made to a busy server, is it possible to get logs particular to that request)?

Throw some ideas, how can we achieve this. Thanks much!

Our application is using below lib for loging:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Which logging library are you using?

Comment: [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527355/log4j-attach-only-one-class-to-an-appender) might help you. Thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate on the 3 W's (what,when,where)?

Comment: When : If there is any issue happened in production (say some login problem in site), I would search for cal logs based for some key "Say User ID".
What: If I can get the Cal logs for that particular thread execution (in which user login was attempted), it could be easy to analize what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

With log4j you can use a mapped diagnostic context(MDC) which is set in a servlet filter, where you can put user, thread name, ip address, whatever you want from the request, to be shown in the log file.  This blog post gives a decent explanation, and a follow-up post with an example http://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/10/log4j-mdc-mapped-diagnostic-context-what-and-why/

Once you have that information in the log file you can use something like chainsaw to view and filter the content.  http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/index.html